# Add onclick event on a php-generated table cell

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to generate an HTML table with dynamic content in PHP, and add an onclick event on a cell of each row, to trigger an action depending on that row.

How to achieve that ?

Here is my example : 
I have a table which prints data from a database. Table is made of 3 columns. Columns 1 and 2 hold name and surname and column 3 refers to a comment. Third column says "Comment exists" or "No comments", depending on whether a related comment exists or not.

The goal is to pop up a small window when user clicks on the third column, to show the given comment.

Here is an example of a table, and what I have tried so far :

```
<table border=1>
   <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Vardas</th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) : ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['vardas'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['gedimas'] ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

How do I add on click event for the `$row['gedimas']` line, to display a full comment from database ?

Comment: I think you can click on "reopen" below your question, to ask moderators to reopen your question now that it's been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place an "onclick" event directly in PHP :

```
<td <?php echo "onclick='displayComment(".$id.")'" ?> >
```

About the general structure of opening a window, you can build the table pretty easily, and then have another page for displaying the comment if there is.

Code for the table :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Has comment ?</th>
  </tr>
<?php
for( $i = 0; $i<count($database_data); $i++){
   $item = $database_data[$i];
   ?><tr>
       <td><?php echo $item[0] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $item[1] ?></td>
       <td <?php 
          echo "onclick='displayComment("
          echo $item[0].", ".$item[1]
          echo ")'"?>
       ><?php echo $item[2] ? "Comment exists" : "No comments" ?></td>
     </tr>
}
```

Then you would need to include a javascript file with the following code :

```
function displayComment(name, surname) {
   window.open(
      "display_comment.php?name="+encodeURI(name)+"&surname="+encodeURI(surname),
      "_blank",
      "height=200, width=300"
}
```

And lastly, you would need your `display_comment.php`page, whose essence would be :

```
// get comment from database using data in $_GET["name"] and $_GET["surname"]

Comment from <?php echo $_GET["name"]." ".$_GET["surname"] ?> : 
<br>
<?php echo $comment_retrieved_from_database ?>
```

### Alternative

An alternative would be to only record the id of the comment in the HTML code, and then add the onclick events in javascript.

The php code for the cell would be as follows :

```
<td <?php echo "data-comment-id='$id'" ?> >
```

And you would add the onclick events in javascript that way :

```
var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-comment-id]");
for(var i=0; i<tableCells.length; i++){
   var cell = tableCells[i];
   var commentId = cell.getAttribute("data-comment-id");
   cell.addEventListener("click", function(){openPopup(commentId);});
}
```

Comment: how that would work with an actual data from database? Could you make a demo version. please

Comment: That would work exactly the way I wrote it. I used an array to represent data from the database, which is what is returned by functions that access a database

Comment: could u apply your code to the updated questions? I gave which row exactly I need to be done in the way I asked.

Comment: This was already included in my answer : see the part where I use <?php echo "onclick='displayComment...." etc. This is how you get an onclick event on this table's cell